# Multiple elements, classes and ID CSS

Tags: html, css

I want these elements to be on the same heights, so when I entered this, it doesn't work, I searched some references and did the same: they put a `,` after every element.

Is there something wrong with my code?

```
html, #app-layout, #page-content-wrapper, #page-content-wrapper > div, #page-content-wrapper > div > div, #page-content-wrapper > div > div > div, #timer {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
```

Comment: You missed `body` in your selector.

Comment: the body, has an id "#app-layout" so i guess it's included?

Comment: You should include your HTML in question as well to get a clear answer.

Comment: oh ok, i'll edit.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Body is not necessory in css. It will work anyway without styling body

Comment: You give all those elements `height: 100%`, it won't work in some occasions. for example, an empty div with `height: 100%` won't be shown at all. please remember that `100%` means "Defines the height in percent of the containing block".
please add some HTML, and it'll be much easier to help you.